# HttpWebRequest to avito.ru -> error

Tags: c#, system.net.httpwebrequest

Need to get HTML from any add out of these: https://www.avito.ru/moskva/kvartiry?user=1

I have the following code:

```
HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        Request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        Request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36";
        Request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*;q=0.8";
        Request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
        Request.Method = "GET";
        Request.Timeout = 10000;
        using (HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse()) { ...;}
```

It used to work just fine untill today. Apparently they have changed something at their web-site and now the last line of the code throw an error, which says:

> System.Net.WebException: Base connection is closed: inexpected error at transfer. ---> System.IO.IOException: connection error because of inexpected packet format.

The thing is, I still have good response from the link at the top.

But it throws an exception at response from something like https://www.avito.ru/moskva/kvartiry/2-k_kvartira_54_m_1617_et._555913941

- browser requests are responded as they should. Even with disabled cookies and JS.

Any Ideas?

ps. error message can be inexact as it's translated. My excuses for grammar..

Comment: Can you share the raw response that you receive from the URL along with the complete HTTP transactions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server droped my requests because I forgot to add "www." to the domain-name for composed url's..
Guys, keep an eye on details.